# php: printing the last 10 lines of all files named error_log in all subdirectories?

Tags: php, unix

I found some ridiculous long code (about 50 lines long) for doing such a thing using php functions, and I just thought there must be a better way.

Then after some searching i found out about 'find' and 'tail' functions of unix.

```
$lines = `find . -name "error_log" -exec tail '{}' +`;
```

However my server is down atm so i cannot test it, but would this work?

EDIT: it is working as expected.

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP if you're asking a unix question?

Comment: im using php to execute the unix command. should it go to unix category then?

Comment: When possible can you accept your own answer?

Answer (score 0):

OK my server just got back up, and it is working perfectly.
No need for recursiveiterator and all that.